# Printing Doubly Linked list

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

I have a homework to write First Come First Serve and Round Robin simulaion and compare them. I started of creating a linked list for making an event list. I have made insert and print_list functions, but couldn't make it work. My friend told me to use Doubly Linked List so I reacreated the linked list and am trying to make print function work. I had a question about my insertion function as I had mistake in order of statements in while loop. After fixing many errors, the print function prints the same node many times, instead of the whole list. I can't which part of the program is wrong. I think that I have error either in insert function and I point pointers wrong, so I get event pointed to itself or I have the error in print function.

When i deleted this line of the code the print function printed only the current node and nothing else.

> newpointer->next = *eventlist;

I think that means that I have problem in this part, but I don't get why.

```
 if(prevptr == NULL)                  //if putting node at the beginning of the list
 {
     printf("DONEW\n");
     newpointer->next = *eventlist;                    
     *eventlist = newpointer;
 }
```

Can you please tell me what's wrong with the code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct event {
       struct event *next;
       int processid;
       int arrivaltime;
       int cputime;
};
typedef struct event Event;
typedef Event *eventPtr;

Event create_node(int processid, int arrivaltime, int cputime);
void add_event(Event *newpointer, eventPtr *eventlist);
void print_node(Event node);
void print_eventlist(Event *eventlist);
Event get_nextevent(Event *eventlist);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int sourcenum,a,b,c,i;
    Event tempevent;
    eventPtr eventlist = NULL;
    print_eventlist(eventlist);
    char* sources,timeSlice;
    if(argc != 3)
    printf("Proper usage is: main.c sources time-slice\n");
    else
    {
        sourcenum = atoi(argv[1]);
        timeSlice = atoi(argv[2]);
        for(i = 0; i < sourcenum ; i++)
        {
              //print_eventlist(&(*eventlist));
              printf("please enter the process-id, arrival-time and cpu-time.\n");
              scanf("%d %d %d",&a, &b, &c);
              printf("something\n");
              tempevent = create_node(a,b,c);
              printf("something\n");
              add_event(&tempevent, &eventlist);
              print_eventlist(eventlist);
        }
        print_eventlist(eventlist);    
    }
    return 0;
}


void add_event(Event *newpointer, eventPtr *eventlist)     //insert
{
     printf("DONE1\n");
     eventPtr currentptr, prevptr;
     printf("DONE2\n");
     prevptr = NULL;
     printf("DONE3\n");
     currentptr = *eventlist;
     printf("DONE4\n");
     while((currentptr != NULL && currentptr->arrivaltime < newpointer->arrivaltime))                  /*on every loop previous and current pointer gets upgraded*/
     {
             printf("DONEW\n");
             prevptr = currentptr;
             currentptr = currentptr->next;   
     }
     printf("DONEW\n");
     if(prevptr == NULL)                  //if putting node at the beginning of the list
     {
         printf("DONEW\n");
         newpointer->next = *eventlist;                    
         *eventlist = newpointer;
     }
     else //putting list between current and previous
     {
         printf("DONEW\n");
         prevptr->next = newpointer;
         newpointer->next = currentptr;
     }
     printf("DONE\n");
}

Event create_node(int processid, int arrivaltime, int cputime)
{
      Event *ptr;
      ptr = malloc(sizeof(Event));
      if(ptr != NULL)
      {
         ptr->processid = processid;       
         ptr->arrivaltime = arrivaltime;    
         ptr->cputime = cputime;
         ptr->next = NULL;
      }
      return *ptr;
}

void print_node(Event node)
{
  printf("process-id = %d\n",node.processid);
  printf("Arrival Time = %d\n",node.arrivaltime);
  printf("CPU time = %d\n",node.cputime);   
}

void print_eventlist(eventPtr currentPtr)                                           /*function receives an eventlist and prints all of the events*/
{
    if(currentPtr == NULL)
    {
        puts("List is empty\n");
    }
    else
    {
        puts("The List is:");
        while(currentPtr != NULL)
        {
            printf("==========================================\n");//list #%d\n",i);
            print_node(*currentPtr);
            printf("\n==========================================\n");
            currentPtr = currentPtr->next;
        }
        puts("NULL\n");
    }
}
    /*int i=0;                                     //This is what I had before
    eventPtr currentptr;
    *currentptr = *eventlist;
    printf("something!!!");
    while(currentptr != NULL)
    {
         i++;
         printf("==========================================\nlist #%d\n",i);
         print_node(*currentptr);
         printf("\n==========================================\n");
         currentptr = currentptr->next;            
    }
}*/

/*Event get_nextevent(Event *eventlist)
{    
    Event newstruct = create_node(eventlist->processid, eventlist->arrivaltime, eventlist->cputime);
    eventlist = eventlist->next;
    return newstruct;  
}*/
```

Comment: instead of returning a local stack object in `create_node`, should return a dynamically (heap-allocated) memory which can be manipulated predictably from the rest of the program. ie return `ptr` not `*ptr`..

Comment: I changed it and it worked, but I don't get why? can you please advise me a book or a page to read about memory allocation. I see that I don't fully understand it.

Comment: Side Bar: You'll just have to trust me when I say that `eventPtr` adds *nothing* to this code. You should be using `Event *`. It will make it *far* easier to read by anyone versed in C.

Comment: @WhozCraig I just saw that style today in my book. I will change it as I didn't like it too. Thx for telling.

Comment: Check out [local memory address is valid after function return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115157/local-memory-address-is-valid-after-function-return) and [Returning local data from functions in C and C++ via pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127507/returning-local-data-from-functions-in-c-and-c-via-pointer), for a bit more info on local memory scope..

Comment: @vatomargvelashvili no worries. C programmers like seeing asterisks. They're big flags that scream "pointer here" etc. Hiding them in a typedef really only has use for exposing opaque "handles" in an api library, or as a type for functions (i.e. `typedef void (*FnCallback)(int, int,int);`. Proponents say they help with f'ed up multi-var decls because `Type* a,b;` doesn't do what it initially appears to , while `TypePtr a,b;` does. Thats an empty argument, however, as doing it wrong (the former) is all-but-guaranteed to break at compile time anyway, and you won't make that mistake again.

Comment: +1 for doing your homework (unlike many here...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the type of:

```
 Event tempevent;
```

to

```
 eventPtr tempevent;
```

The problem you have is that you pass &tempevent and with Event tempevent, this address is always the same. Change the create_node to return an eventPtr too.

```
eventPtr create_node(int processid, int arrivaltime, int cputime)
{
      Event *ptr;
      ptr = malloc(sizeof(Event));
      if(ptr != NULL)
      {
         ptr->processid = processid;       
         ptr->arrivaltime = arrivaltime;    
         ptr->cputime = cputime;
         ptr->next = NULL;
      }
      return ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There a a multitude of things to address in this code.

First, you're leaking memory in `create_node`. That function should be designed to dynamically allocate an event, prepare it with the passed parameters, and return it to the caller as an address to be assigned to a pointer on the caller-side:

```
Event* create_node(int processid, int arrivaltime, int cputime)
{
    Event *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        perror("Failed to allocate Event.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ptr->processid = processid;
    ptr->arrivaltime = arrivaltime;
    ptr->cputime = cputime;
    ptr->next = NULL;
    return ptr;
}
```

Next, your `add_event` function should take an event pointer as the list head, and ideally the address of said-pointer to allow it to be modified on initial-insert. Two schools of thought prevail for insertion functions, (1) always return the list head, and (2) use a pointer-to-pointer for the list head parameter, and modify it via dereference as needed. I prefer the latter, as it makes the code *very* simple. Even more so in your case since new event creation is done somewhere else.

```
// link an event on to the end of our linked list.
void add_event(Event** pp, Event* event)
{
    while (*pp)
        pp = &(*pp)->next;
    *pp = event;
}
```

Once those are taken care of, the source in `main()` also becomes significantly simpler, taking into account I've also fixed the improper `timeSlice` variable, which was `char` and should have been `int`. More importantly, the logic you had would have a blank list head node, which buys you nothing. You can use a pointer, then call our `add_event` function and pass its address. It will properly insert the node.

The final product looks like this (with minor mods):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct event
{
    struct event *next;
    int processid;
    int arrivaltime;
    int cputime;
} Event;

Event* create_node(int processid, int arrivaltime, int cputime);
void add_event(Event** head, Event *event);
void print_node(const Event* node);
void print_eventlist(const Event *eventlist);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int sourcenum,a,b,c,i,timeslice;
    Event* events = NULL;

    if(argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Proper usage is: main.c sources time-slice\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // TODO: these really should be using strtol() for better
    //  error detection. left as exercise for author.
    sourcenum = atoi(argv[1]);
    timeslice = atoi(argv[2]);

    for(i = 0; i < sourcenum ; i++)
    {
        printf("please enter the process-id, arrival-time and cpu-time.\n");
        if (scanf("%d %d %d",&a, &b, &c) == 3)
        {
            add_event(&events, create_node(a,b,c));
            print_eventlist(events);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

// link an event on to the end of a linked list.
void add_event(Event** pp, Event* event)
{
    while (*pp)
        pp = &(*pp)->next;
    *pp = event;
}

Event* create_node(int processid, int arrivaltime, int cputime)
{
    Event *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        perror("Failed to allocate Event.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ptr->processid = processid;
    ptr->arrivaltime = arrivaltime;
    ptr->cputime = cputime;
    ptr->next = NULL;
    return ptr;
}

void print_node(const Event* node)
{
    if (node != NULL)
    {
        printf("process-id = %d\n",node->processid);
        printf("Arrival Time = %d\n",node->arrivaltime);
        printf("CPU time = %d\n",node->cputime);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("NULL\n");
    }
}

void print_eventlist(const Event* currentPtr)
{
    puts("==========================================");
    while(currentPtr != NULL)
    {
        print_node(currentPtr);
        puts("==========================================");
        currentPtr = currentPtr->next;
    }
    puts("NULL");
    puts("==========================================");//list #%d\n",i);
}
```

**Sample Output**

Obtained from a command line requesting 5 entries.

```
please enter the process-id, arrival-time and cpu-time.
1 1 1 
==========================================
process-id = 1
Arrival Time = 1
CPU time = 1
==========================================
NULL
==========================================
please enter the process-id, arrival-time and cpu-time.
2 2 2 
==========================================
process-id = 1
Arrival Time = 1
CPU time = 1
==========================================
process-id = 2
Arrival Time = 2
CPU time = 2
==========================================
NULL
==========================================
please enter the process-id, arrival-time and cpu-time.
3 3 3 
==========================================
process-id = 1
Arrival Time = 1
CPU time = 1
==========================================
process-id = 2
Arrival Time = 2
CPU time = 2
==========================================
process-id = 3
Arrival Time = 3
CPU time = 3
==========================================
NULL
==========================================
please enter the process-id, arrival-time and cpu-time.
4 4 4
==========================================
process-id = 1
Arrival Time = 1
CPU time = 1
==========================================
process-id = 2
Arrival Time = 2
CPU time = 2
==========================================
process-id = 3
Arrival Time = 3
CPU time = 3
==========================================
process-id = 4
Arrival Time = 4
CPU time = 4
==========================================
NULL
==========================================
please enter the process-id, arrival-time and cpu-time.
5 5 5
==========================================
process-id = 1
Arrival Time = 1
CPU time = 1
==========================================
process-id = 2
Arrival Time = 2
CPU time = 2
==========================================
process-id = 3
Arrival Time = 3
CPU time = 3
==========================================
process-id = 4
Arrival Time = 4
CPU time = 4
==========================================
process-id = 5
Arrival Time = 5
CPU time = 5
==========================================
NULL
==========================================
```

Anyway, hope it gives you some good ideas.